# Lucene limit file size while saving into data base

Tags: lucene

I'm new in luene and i want to save the index file into data base but i have this exeption and i would not change the max_allowed_packet but i want to limit the size of file.

```
Exception in thread "Lucene Merge Thread #0" org.apache.lucene.index.MergePolicy$MergeException: org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.JdbcStoreException: Failed to execute sql [insert into search_lucene (name_, value_, size_, lf_, deleted_) values ( ?, ?, ?, current_timestamp, ? )]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (1286944 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable. 
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.handleMergeException(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:309) 
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:286) 
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.JdbcStoreException: Failed to execute sql [insert into search_lucene (name_, value_, size_, lf_, deleted_) values ( ?, ?, ?, current_timestamp, ? )]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (1286944 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable. 
        at org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.support.JdbcTemplate.executeUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:185) 
        at org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.index.AbstractJdbcIndexOutput.close(AbstractJdbcIndexOutput.java:47) 
        at org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.index.RAMAndFileJdbcIndexOutput.close(RAMAndFileJdbcIndexOutput.java:81) 
        at org.apache.lucene.index.CompoundFileWriter.close(CompoundFileWriter.java:203) 
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.createCompoundFile(SegmentMerger.java:204) 
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4263) 
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3884) 
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:205) 
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:260) 
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (1286944 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet' variable. 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3915) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2598) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2459) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2376) 
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2360) 
        at org.apache.lucene.store.jdbc.support.JdbcTemplate.executeUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:175)
```

Answer (score 1):

read from http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Can_I_store_the_Lucene_index_in_a_relational_database.3F

**Can I store the Lucene index in a relational database?**

Lucene does not support that functionality out of the box, but several people have implemented JdbcDirectory's. The reports we have seen so far indicate that ***performance with such implementations is not great***, but it is doable.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the file size you'll need to implement a Directory yourself. The trick is to split every file into parts. Perhaps you can borrow some code from [lucene-appengine](http://code.google.com/p/lucene-appengine/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/lucene/appengine/), which splits the file into multiple `SegmentHunk`s.

I hope you know what you're doing because keeping lucene indexes in a database will be much slower than using the usual memory-mapped files.

Comment: I'm trying to put all the memory-mapped files in a .cfs file ( compound file ) and save it in the database, to keep a copy of my index securised in the DB, I know it's an additionnal work, do you mean that the .cfs file will be divised in multiple files then saved in the database?

Comment: Yes, I mean just that. But if all you want is to archive the index into the database, then I suggest you split it with your archival program. For example, with 7z you can split the archive using the "-v" option: `7zr a -v1m archive.7z cfsFile`.

Comment: I use JDBCDIRECTORY its responsible for the insertion and retrieval of  file into  database so I can't archived it,you have not other sonution to limit the file **.cfs** size when indexing

Comment: Why should there be another solution? Either tweak the MySQL maximum packet size or implement the splitting in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

essaies :

```
indexWriter.setUseCompoundFile(false);

LogByteSizeMergePolicy aLogByteSizeMergePolicy = new LogByteSizeMergePolicy();
aLogByteSizeMergePolicy.setMaxMergeMB(2);
aLogByteSizeMergePolicy.setMaxMergeMBForForcedMerge(4);
aLogByteSizeMergePolicy.setUseCompoundFile(false);
//voir aussi setMaxCFSSegmentSizeMB, setMaxMergeDocs, setMergeFactor

indexWriter.setMergePolicy(aLogByteSizeMergePolicy);
//Deprecated. use IndexWriterConfig.setMergePolicy(MergePolicy) instead.
```

Comment: ces propriétés ne limitent que la taille du segment dans le fichier mais pas la taille totale